# Select dataset records by dates from last 7 week days

Tags: python, date, filter

Given below dataset, I want to filter all records which have dates belonging to last 7 week days.

```
record_id,date,site,sick,funny,happy
CDEC1947-6,9/2/2018,2,1,1,1
IJKC1953-4,9/29/2018,2,1,1,1
FGHC1724-9,10/25/2018,2,3,1,1
FGHC2929-1,10/31/2018,4,1,1,1
CDEC1912-0,11/1/2018,1,1,1,1
IJKC1726-4,11/2/2018,1,3,1,1
IJKC1728-0,10/26/2018,2,3,1,1
ABCC1730-6,11/2/2018,2,3,1,1
ABCC1731-4,11/2/2018,2,3,1,1
CDEC1733-0,10/22/2018,1,3,1,1
CDEC1735-5,11/2/2018,2,3,1,1
IJKC1914-6,10/27/2018,2,6,1,1
ABCC1916-1,10/23/2018,2,6,1,1
IJKC1918-7,11/2/2018,2,1,1,1
CDEC1920-3,10/24/2018,1,6,1,1
IJKC1943-5,11/2/2018,2,4,1,1
ABCC1945-0,11/2/2018,1,4,1,1
ABCC1949-2,10/25/2018,2,4,1,1
CDEC1951-8,11/2/2018,2,5,1,1
CDEC2924-2,11/3/2018,4,1,1,1
CDEC2927-5,11/3/2018,1,1,1,1
ABCC2925-9,11/4/2018,4,1,1,1
IJKC1941-9,11/4/2018,2,4,1,1
ABCC2922-6,11/5/2018,1,1,1,1
```

I have tried many tricks without success.
One of them the below:

```
df['data_recrutamento'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_recrutamento'])

m1 = (df['sick'] == 1) | (df['funny'] == 1) | (df['happy'] == 1)  
m2 = df['date'] >= pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=7)  
m3 = ~df['date'].dt.weekday.isin([5, 6])                         

dates_last7_weekdays = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'site'].value_counts()
dates_last7_weekdays

dates_last7_weekdays = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'site'].value_counts()
dates_last7_weekdays
```

Other attempt example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
today = date.today()
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
%matplotlib inline

df=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", encoding="utf-8",low_memory=False)

df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["site"]=df["site"].astype("category") # Convert to category
df['sick']=df['sick'].astype('category')
df["funny"]=df["funny"].astype("category")
df["happy"]=df["happy"].astype("category")

df = df.sort_values(by='date', ascending='True')
df.head()

    record_id   date    site    sick    funny   happy
0   CDEC1947-6  2018-09-02  2   1   1   1
1   IJKC1953-4  2018-09-29  2   1   1   1
9   CDEC1733-0  2018-10-22  1   3   1   1
12  ABCC1916-1  2018-10-23  2   6   1   1
14  CDEC1920-3  2018-10-24  1   6   1   1
2   FGHC1724-9  2018-10-25  2   3   1   1
17  ABCC1949-2  2018-10-25  2   4   1   1
6   IJKC1728-0  2018-10-26  2   3   1   1
11  IJKC1914-6  2018-10-27  2   6   1   1
3   FGHC2929-1  2018-10-31  4   1   1   1
4   CDEC1912-0  2018-11-01  1   1   1   1
7   ABCC1730-6  2018-11-02  2   3   1   1
10  CDEC1735-5  2018-11-02  2   3   1   1
5   IJKC1726-4  2018-11-02  1   3   1   1
13  IJKC1918-7  2018-11-02  2   1   1   1
15  IJKC1943-5  2018-11-02  2   4   1   1
16  ABCC1945-0  2018-11-02  1   4   1   1
18  CDEC1951-8  2018-11-02  2   5   1   1
8   ABCC1731-4  2018-11-02  2   3   1   1
19  CDEC2924-2  2018-11-03  4   1   1   1
20  CDEC2927-5  2018-11-03  1   1   1   1
22  IJKC1941-9  2018-11-04  2   4   1   1
21  ABCC2925-9  2018-11-04  4   1   1   1
23  ABCC2922-6  2018-11-05  1   1   1   1

days_diff = []
for i in df.loc[:, 'date']:
    days_diff.append(((datetime.datetime.today() - i).days))

final=df[(pd.Series(days_diff) <= 7) & ((df.loc[:, 'sick'] == 1)|(df.loc[:, 'funny'] == 1)|(df.loc[:, 'happy'] == 1) )] 

C:\Users\H\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:10: UserWarning:

Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

len(final)
21

final

    record_id   date    site    sick    funny   happy
9   CDEC1733-0  2018-10-22  1   3   1   1
12  ABCC1916-1  2018-10-23  2   6   1   1
14  CDEC1920-3  2018-10-24  1   6   1   1
17  ABCC1949-2  2018-10-25  2   4   1   1
11  IJKC1914-6  2018-10-27  2   6   1   1
10  CDEC1735-5  2018-11-02  2   3   1   1
13  IJKC1918-7  2018-11-02  2   1   1   1
15  IJKC1943-5  2018-11-02  2   4   1   1
16  ABCC1945-0  2018-11-02  1   4   1   1
18  CDEC1951-8  2018-11-02  2   5   1   1
19  CDEC2924-2  2018-11-03  4   1   1   1
20  CDEC2927-5  2018-11-03  1   1   1   1
22  IJKC1941-9  2018-11-04  2   4   1   1
21  ABCC2925-9  2018-11-04  4   1   1   1
23  ABCC2922-6  2018-11-05  1   1   1   1
```

But my desired result should only be in maximum 7 different dates in rows and not more than that because I just want to filter last 7 week days using today's date as my reference. So, according to the dataset my aimed output should not include these dates as they are in the weekends 2018-11-04, 2018-11-03 and these dates 2018-10-22, 2018-10-23, 2018-10-24, 2018-10-25 and 2018-10-27 should not be included as they are not part of last 7 weekdays. So, my final output should only be:

```
record_id   date    site    sick    funny   happy
10  CDEC1735-5  2018-11-02  2   3   1   1
13  IJKC1918-7  2018-11-02  2   1   1   1
15  IJKC1943-5  2018-11-02  2   4   1   1
16  ABCC1945-0  2018-11-02  1   4   1   1
18  CDEC1951-8  2018-11-02  2   5   1   1
23  ABCC2922-6  2018-11-05  1   1   1   1
```

Because those dates belong to the date interval corresponding to the last 7 weekdays from 2018-11-06 to 2018-11-29 (reference is today when I am writing this 2018-11-06 but tomorrow shoulb be 2018-11-07).

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward way is to subtract and find day differences, and use it for subseting. We use `datetime.datetime.today()` in order to get today's datetime. We then use that datetime to subtract each entry from your `df.loc[:, 'dates']` column. To make sure that we will not get time along with the days difference, we use the `(...).days` at the end. We then use the comparative less than or equal operation to create a boolean series, indicating which entries are less than or equal to 7 days. Fianlly, we use that boolean series to filter our data frame

```
import datetime

days_diff = []
for i in df.loc[:, 'date']:
    days_diff.append(((datetime.datetime.today() - i).days))

#subset your data frame
df[pd.Series(days_diff) <= 7]
#or to include the other conditions as well,
df[(pd.Series(days_diff) <= 7) & ((df.loc[:, 'sick'] == 1)|(df.loc[:, 'funny'] == 1)|(df.loc[:, 'happy'] == 1) )]
```

**NOTE:** Convert your `date` column to proper datetime first

Comment: It works but outputs 20 differents day on my real dataset. Also gives this warning: C:\Users\H\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: UserWarning:

Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

Comment: Please, add some more comments to your code, I liked it very much, its very clean and few lines of code. Thanks

Comment: @MGB.py, I hope it's clear now. Let me know If you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks for the comments but what about this condition to the filter?
(df['sick'] == 1) | (df['funny'] == 1) | (df['happy'] == 1) 
Sorry

Comment: Edited to include other conditions as well

Comment: please, check my update, look at other attempt example.